# css import <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css"> doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to import a ccs file in HTML. But, it doesn't seem to work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
```

This is my file structure:

[image]

If I use the script tag it works. I also tried to use `style.css` instead of `style/style.css` but still the same problem.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using importing the css file in `giocatori.ejs` ??

Comment: you have to use: `../style/style.css` as path. From your `.ejs` file you first have to go one folder below with `../`. If this solves the issue then this soley is a typo caused issue and as such please remove the question voluntarily before more users try to answer instead of closing it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're putting this in the head section it should work.

Try adding some obvious change to your css to see if it's linking for example:

```
body {
background-color: red;}
```

Comment: nothing happens

Answer (score -1):

I don't see in your directory listing where your html files are. But if they're not in the directory above "style", then you'll want to change your link to:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/style.css">
```

i.e. add a slash before "style", so that rather expecting the directory to sit within the current directory of the html, you'll point to the style directory as being at the top level of the site.

Comment: the html is the .ejs is called like that because i'm using ejs to use more comfortably javascipt into html, but it works the same way

Comment: technical incorrect. YOu have to use `../` to go one folder below in a file structure. just `/` will do nothing. Despite that. This would be a typo caused issue and should not be answered but commented instead (yes I'm aware that you unlock comments at 50 reputation).

Comment: Sorry @tacoshy, but the leading slash has always (for web stuff) said to start at the web root, and certainly "does something." "../" means "up a folder from where you currently are, and of course if where you "currently are" is one level below root, they end up pointing to the same thing. But that's not a general solution for finding your css file, imo, better to point directly to where it is, a common way in all your html. Here's a link to the description: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp